# Create tables from views in another database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two different DB, one with views and one empty.
I need to create tables in the empty DB from the DB with the views.

It's need to update from the views every 20 sec.
The empty DB probably will be SQL-Server.

How can i do this?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: To be updated from a view every 20 sec? sounds inefficient .

Comment: Write a procedure to do all of the INSERT Statements. Then add the proc to a job to [execute recurring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job) every 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what exactly you are trying to do.

But for this part:

> I need to create tables in the empty DB from the DB with the views.

You can use [`INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql) like this:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM yourView;
```

So this will copy the same columns in the `SELECT` statement and create a new table from it.

But there is no need to do this for each couple of seconds. Maybe you need to sync the data after that each interval of time. And this can be done with sql job.

**UPDATE:**

If the table and view are in different servers, you have to use a [fully qualified table name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx). But first you have to create a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine) between the two servers.

```
SELECT * INTO [servername].Database.new_table FROM yourView;
```

Comment: If every DB on different server?

Comment: @tal - Just use fully qualified table names.

Comment: I don't understand you.can you give me an example?